# pass large data between programs in c++ and php

Tags: php, c++, fifo

I need to develop two programs on linux: *cpp_prog* is a small program written in c++. It monitors a message queue system. Once a message is available at the queue system, the program downloads the message and then call another php program, say *php_prog*, to process the message and read the output from php_prog. When php_prog is finished, cpp_prog will get back the control and listen to the message queue system again. This process will continue forever.

My question is that How to pass large data from c++ to php and read output of the php program.

Message could be very long, so system call in c++ `system("php_prog message_string");` would not be a good choice.

I tried with fifo too. in cpp_prog

```
int fifo = open(fifo_name.c_str(), O_WRONLY);
write(fifo, msg_string.c_str(), strlen(msg_string.c_str()));
close(fifo);
system("php_prog fifo_name"); //call php_prog with fifo name
```

in php_prog:

```
$fifo = $argv[1];
var_dump($fifo);
$str_content = file_get_contents($fifo);
echo "here is msg\n";
var_dump($str_content);
echo "end\n";
```

But cpp_prog is blocked untill I call "php_prog fifo_name" from somewhere else (e.g. a terminal) to read the fifo.

I am open for any suggestions (but I really will avoid using tmp file). Would be very good if you can provide a simple codes.

BR

Comment: Have you considered writing a PHP module that just pops one large object from the queue and returns it to PHP as a string? Other than that, using e.g. a file or shared memory would be two approaches I would consider. Maybe even using ZeroMQ on top of shared memory as IPC in between, to allow easy extending and rapid prototyping.

Comment: thanks for your help. But the system architecture of using c++ to fetch message and php to parse it is appointed. I unfortunately cannot change this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally use `popen` in c++ and `file_get_contents` in php to fix the problem.

in cpp_prog:

```
FILE* fp = popen(cmd.c_str(), "w");
fwrite(msg_string.c_str(), sizeof (char), msg_string.size(), fp);
fflush(fp);
pclose(fp);
```

in php_prog:

```
$msg_content = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
echo "here is msg\n";
var_dump($msg_content);
echo "end\n";
```